# Google Places Service giving undefined error

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places

So i recently started to use Maps Api v3 and I am getting and undefined error when I try to make a nearby search. On this line `var service_places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);`

```
function setupMap (position) {
// console.log(position);
var curLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
// console.log(curLocation);
var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map-container');
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: curLocation,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    }
};
map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer,mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
    position: curLocation,
    map: map,
    title: "I am here :)"   
});
getNearMe(curLocation);
}


function getNearMe (curLocation) {
var request = {
    loacation: curLocation,
    radius: '10000',
    types: ['bar', 'night_club']
};
var service_places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service_places.nearbySearch(request,function (response,status) {
    console.log(status);
    console.log(response);
});

}
```

`<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MY-KEY>-fSUI&sensor=false">
    </script>`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#loading_the_library

Answer (score 6):

You should include places library in your google api link.

Please try this in index.html:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Fixed my problem, thanks. But what does libraries=places actually do?

Comment: Places Service library is separated from the main Maps API JavaScript code... libraries=palaces is needed to link this separated one.

Comment: while using this script, due to "sensor=true" I am not able to see the map. after removing it, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few errors off the bat. For example "location" is misspelled in your request variable.

You also should declare your map variable with "var map". But that's just a style issue. Fix these and see if it works and then we can troubleshoot more.

Comment: As Dr.Molle pointed out by linking the documentation. The api doesn't support json or jsonp, this has to be done through the google maps javascript api or server side scripting. Thanks.